# Flutter: How to call openDrawer from other widget

Tags: flutter, dart

**Question:** I want to call openDrawer from  onPressed() of  Header.dart

The Drawer.dart, Header.dart and Home.dart files are separate.

I have tried`Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();` 
not worked.

I tried using `cotroller` but it not work.
Perhaps it was not used in the right way.

I would appreciate any advice you could give me.

**code:**

Codes are omitted.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Header('App'),
      endDrawer: Menu(),
    )}}
```

```
class Header extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const Header(this.heading, {Key? key});
  final String heading;
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  State<Header> createState() => _HeaderState(heading);
}

class _HeaderState extends State<Header> {
  _HeaderState(this.heading);

  final String heading;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: false,
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30.0),
          tooltip: '',
          onPressed: () {
            // _key.currentState!.openDrawer();
          },
        ),]
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  const Menu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an end drawer, so instead of `Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()`, you should use `Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer()`:

```
class _HeaderState extends State<Header> {
  _HeaderState(this.heading);

  final String heading;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: false,
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30.0),
          tooltip: '',
          onPressed: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
          },
        ),]
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Side Note**: You don't need to pass arguments from the `StatefulWidget` to the `State` - Every instance of `State` has a `widget` property, which you can use to access the properties of the parent widget.

In your case it would look like:

```
class Header extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const Header(this.heading, {Key? key});

  final String heading;

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);

  @override
  State<Header> createState() => _HeaderState();
}

class _HeaderState extends State<Header> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      centerTitle: false,

      // Assuming this is what the heading argument is for
      title: Text(widget.heading), 

      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.menu, size: 30.0),
          tooltip: '',
          onPressed: () {
            Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it